# Speed Up Execution Time of Select Query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, select, query-performance

My question may sound childish, but I am really googling a lot regarding this issue. I have a table **tblUsers** where 20 columns are present (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress....), which has around 91,000 data.

When I use Select Query

`Select * from tblUsers`

It takes around 2 min 27 seconds to complete execution.

**Is It really any way to speed up the execution time**

Any type of suggestions will be welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add, DESC TABLE tlbUsers; in detail, also EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tblUsers; for better results try adding where clause to query, simple select is going to take too long as all the records are fetched.

Comment: Network problem?  Is the server on the far side of the moon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is It really any way to speed up the execution time

You are running `Select * from tblUsers` and expecting it to be fast? You are selecting all columns and all rows from a table, so it will take its own time to return the result set. If there is a clustered index, an index scan would be used, and if the table is a heap, a table scan would be used.

If you want to increase the speed, you either have to add a WHERE clause to make query sargable or limit the number of columns, although the latter will not affect the execution time so much.

Also, if your data file lies on a fast storage (SSDs, Flash Drives, as compared to SATA disks), the query is likely to become faster.

**Moral:** If you are running `select *` on a table, don't expect the query to be fast, it would take its own time to retrieve all rows. If you are on a production system, running `select *` would really be a performance killer, so avoid it.

Comment: Sure, will keep in mind @Shanky

Answer (score 1):

I am  not a Developer indeed but from my administration experience

My Suggestions would be :

1. Review the Execution Plan
2. Add Indexes
3. Optimize Your SQL Structure and Joins
4. Eliminate Unnecessary Data
5. Analyze Your Server Specifications and Performance

Comment: My approach is pretty straight forward...can you give me an example@SQLBoy

Comment: How would index help when you run select * on a table.